# Discrete filter bode shows wrong results

Tags: matlab

I have a discrete Filter consisting of the difference of two FIR filters. One filter is multiplied with 0.5, the other is delayed by z^-1. But at the end the bode diagram seems not correct and also when I let myself display the resulting function, it is not what I have calculated. Where is my fault?

```
Ts = 1;
FIR1 = tf([-0.1675, 0.1750, 0.3500, -0.2250, -0.1675, -0.1250], 1, Ts);  
FIR2 = tf([0.1250, -0.5850, 0.8500, -0.3000, 0.0500, -0.5850, -0.1250], 1, Ts);
H_1 = FIR1 * tf(1, [1 0], Ts); 
H_2 = 0.5 * FIR2;
H_diff = H_1 - H_2;
figure;
bode(H_diff)
```

Comment: I didn't run your code, but the fourth line seems to multiply the first transfer function by `1/(z+1)`. Is that intented to delay the impulse response by 1, i.e. multiply by the transfer function by `z^-1`? I don't think that line does that. I've never used transfer function objects in Matlab, though.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer. Yes, my intention is to delay the transfer function by z^-1. Is there any other way to delay it?

Comment: You probably want to delay the _impulse response_, not the transfer function. Delaying the impulse response by 1 time sample corresponds to multiplying the transfer function by z^-1. So I would try that. But I'm not familiar with Matlab's `tf`  (nor do I have that toolbox installed)